# How to continue loop till a keyword is entered java

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class BoxOffice {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inData;
        int age;
        String keyword = ("stop");
        System.out.println("Enter your age:");
        inData = stdin.nextLine();
        age = Integer.parseInt(inData); // convert inData to int
        if (age < 17 && age > 4) {
            System.out.println("Child rate.");
        }
        if (age < 5) {
            System.out.println("baby rate");
        }
        if (age < 60 && age > 17) {
            System.out.println("Adult rate");
        }
        if (age > 60) {
            System.out.println("Senior rate.");

            System.out.println("Enjoy the show."); // always executed
        }
    }

}
```

How do I create a loop so that it will keep taking inputs and telling me the rate until a keyword is entered. I've been searching and trying different loops but none seem to work properly

Comment: You will want to show us your best attempt, using a while loop or a do-while loop. Also, your code was posted without any indentations making it all left justified and almost impossible to read, understand and debug. Fortunately BackSlash fixed this, but in the future, please re-format your posted code by giving it proper indentations, usually 4 spaces per block, and making sure that all code on the same block is on the same indentation level. Your cooperation in this would be greatly appreciated and will likely improve your chances of getting a decent and prompt answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a while loop that continues as long as your input does not equal your desired keyword.

```
while(!(inData = stdin.nextLine()).equals("myKeyword")) {
    //Your code here
}
```